# Accessing a secure EJB as anonymous user on Wildfly 9

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, ejb, wildfly

I have the following setup: Wildfly 9 serving remote EJB clients as well as having some TimerTask instances running that perform some logic.

Most EJB methods are called by remote clients and therefore secured (via @RolesAllowed).
Now, some of these methods will also be called by TimerTask within the server, and in that case I have no principal or security context, which causes the EJB method calls to fail.

My workaround is like this:

EJB:

```
@RolesAllowed({"readRole"})
public void readSomething() {
    this.readSomethingImpl();
}


public void readSomethingUnrestricted() {
    this.readSomethingImpl();
}
```

The readSomething() is part of the remote interface, the readSomethingUnrestricted() is part of the local interface.

The downside is that I have a rather large set of EJB service methods and I do not want to duplicate all of them (one restricted for remote, one unrestricted for local calls).

Is there any better way to implement this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish what you want by annotating your timer tasks with [@javax.annotation.security.RunAs("readRole")](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/security/RunAs.html).

Comment: Thank you Steve. Unfortunately the issue remains. Looking at the docs, this annotation is at the class level. Still getting the same error. Maybe it makes a difference that my TimerTask is part of a WAR inside of an EAR, that tries to "speak" to an EJB in a JAR of the same EAR.